# How to add a property to an object's property that is dynamically named

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, properties, addition

```
var aaa = new Object;
var bbb = 2;
var ccc = 5;
aaa[bbb].description = differentObject.ccc.description;

console.log(aaa.bbb.description);  //will report "undefined"
```

what I need, is to create a property "description" for each new value of bbb and assign a value to it
inside the object aaa. (in my code, this, except the declaration of aaa) runs in a loop and bbb, ccc values change with each cycle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.b` is equivalent to `a["b"]` so when you're doing `aaa.bbb` you're not doing anything related to the `bbb` variable.

`aaa[bbb].description` this is correct to set a property on `aaa[bbb]`, however, `aaa[bbb]` needs to be an object.

An easier way do to this would be:

```
var aaa = {};
var bbb = 2;
var ccc = 5;
aaa[bbb] = {description: differentObject[ccc].description};
```